# Skipping some files when building new gem

Tags: ruby, security, rubygems, bundler

I've never built my own gem before, so this is a totally new experience. I've built a library for my employer, which has to connect to a database of ours in order to run some of my tests. I want to make sure this `config.yml` file isn't included in the gem when I publish it. I've added it to the `.gitignore` file, as I know to do that, but is there some other change I have to make to the `.gemspec` maybe? Or does bundler only include files it knows about when releasing the library to the public? Just trying to be cautious, first time publishing open source code!

---

Specification after @Oleander replied:

Running `git ls-files` in the command line doesn't include the file I want to remove, and my `spec.require_paths` in the `.gemspec` file reads like this: `["lib"]`. The `spec` directory isn't there. Does that mean the `config.yml` file won't be included when I release the gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `config.yml` from `s.files` in your `project.gemspec` file inside your project and the file wont show up in your .gem-file.

```
s.files = `git ls-files`.split($/)
s.files -= ["spec/config.yml"]
```

Comment: Ok cool. Right now my `spec.files` is assigned to the following `\`git ls-files\`.split($/)`. I can't seem to find a way to word a Google search on viewing the state of my gem as it is, so I don't know what that attribute looks like when it's evaluated? Could you help steer me in the right direction, or give me a hint as to how to customize this to remove a `spec/config.yml` file from the attribute?